# Generating of primes in base-3 edited

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

How to prove the following statement!

for example primes  $p_1$ = $7$ = $n$ and $p_2$ = $13$ = $2n-1$(each prime is $> 3$), then $m = p_1 p_2$ is a Fermat-pseudo prime in base-3.

Can we prove it! I have checked for many such primes by trail and error method.

High regards,

Zovi

Comment: Do you mean Fermat pseudoprimes? Also, it seems that what you meant is different from what you have asked. What do you mean "for example" and "checked for many such primes by trial and error"? Given the question is exactly what you meant, you just need to check whether $3^{90}$ is $1$ modulo $91$, no?

Comment: @BalarkaSen! Yes I am looking for Fermat Psedudoprimes in base 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to prove the

**Proposition:** If $p > 3$ is a prime such that $q = 2p-1$ is also a prime, then $m = pq$ is a base-$3$ Fermat pseudoprime.

We have $3^{m-1}\equiv 1 \pmod{m}$ if and only if both, $3^{m-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ and $3^{m-1}\equiv 1 \pmod{q}$ hold. We should look at $m-1$ and Fermat's theorem to see if we can prove it.

$$m-1 = pq-1 = p(2p-1)-1 = (2p+1)(p-1),$$

so $a^{m-1}\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ for all $a$ not divisible by $p$. Since $p > 3$, it follows that $3^{m-1}\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. To treat $q$, we write

$$m-1 = pq-1 = p(q-1) + (p-1) = p(q-1)+ \frac{q-1}{2}.$$

Thus, for $a \not\equiv 0 \pmod{q}$, we have by Fermat's theorem

$$a^{m-1} = \left(a^{q-1}\right)^p\cdot a^{\frac{q-1}{2}} \equiv a^{\frac{q-1}{2}} \pmod{q},$$

so $m$ is a base-$a$ Fermat pseudoprime if and only if $\gcd (a,m) = 1$ and $a^{(q-1)/2} \equiv 1 \pmod{q}$. The latter is the case if and only if $a$ is a quadratic residue modulo $q$, $\left(\frac{a}{q}\right) = 1$. Now if $p > 3$ is a prime such that $q = 2p-1$ is also prime, then

1. $p \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$, which gives us $q \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, and
2. $p \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$, which gives us $q \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$.

For if we had $p \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$, then $2p-1 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ and $q$ would not be a prime.

To finish the proof we observe

$$\begin{align}
\left(\frac{3}{q}\right) &= \left(\frac{q}{3}\right) \tag{$q \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$}\\
&= 1, \tag{$q \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$}
\end{align}$$

so $3$ is a quadratic residue modulo $q$.

Comment: !excellent and sir can your prove my second problem of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616204/fermat-primes-re-edited